# Bothering frame on matplotlib 3D plots

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, 3d

I make 3d plots with matplotlib and I always get a weird frame with a normalized scale around my plot. Where does it come from and how can I get rid of it ?

Here is an example code that drives me to the problem :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D



x = np.linspace(0,10)
y = np.linspace(0,10)
z = np.linspace(0,10)

# ------------- Figure ---------------
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (9,6))

ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.plot(np.sin(x), np.cos(y), z)

plt.show()
```

And here is the result :
[image]

I use `plt.subplots()` because I want a figure with a 3D and a 2D plot side by side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call `plt.subplots(...)` and this, of course, instantiates an Axes, complete of horizontal and vertical spines, ***before*** Matplotlib is informed that you want a 3D enabled Axes.

When you later call `plt.gca(...)` it's too late…

Simply use

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (9,6), subplot_kw={"projection" : "3d"})
```

or

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (9,6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
```

---

*Addressing OP's comment*

[image]

[`Figure.add_subplot`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html?highlight=figure%20add_subplot#matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_subplot) is pretty flexible…

```
fig = plt.figure()
fig.add_subplot(1,5,(1,4), projection='3d')
fig.add_subplot(1,5,5)
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it partially solve my problem. I haven't been that clear on what I want to do. If I use ```plt.subplots()``` it's because I want to plot an other graph that is not 3D but 2D. 
With the first  correction you give, it plots all the subplots in 3D projection. And with the second method it overlaps the plots.

Comment: Thanks ! Using ```add_suplot``` and ```add_gridspec``` Imanaged to do what I wanted to. The combinaison of both is more reliable than ```plt;subplots```